# Evaluate $\int\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x-3}}{x+1}d\,x$ by trig substitution

Tags: integration

I am preparing for an exam and found this integral in a previous test. Did I do it correctly?

My attempt.

$$
\int\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x-3}}{x+1}\,dx
$$
Complete the square of $x^2+2x-3$; I changed the integral to
$$
\int\frac{\sqrt{(x-1)^2-4}}{x+1}\,dx
$$
then set $u=x+1$ to get
$$
\int\frac{\sqrt{u^2-4}}{u}\,dx
$$
Using the triangle, $2\sec\theta=u$ and $du=2\sec\theta\tan\theta d\theta$
$$
\int\frac{\sqrt{(2\sec\theta)^2-2^2}}{2\sec\theta}2\sec\theta \tan\theta\, d\theta
$$
This I simplified to 
$$
2\int\tan^2\theta\, d\theta = 2\int\sec^2\theta-1\,d\theta
=2[\tan\theta-\theta]+C
$$

Back substitute
$$
\theta=\tan^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{u^2-4}}{2}
$$
and
$$
\tan\theta=\frac{\sqrt{u^2-4}}{2}
$$
Back substitute $u=x+1$
$$
\int\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x-3}}{x+1}\,dx=
\sqrt{(x-1)^2-4}-\tan^{-1}{\sqrt{(x-1)^2-4}}+C
$$

Comment: If you just need a verification. You can use wolfram alpha

Comment: if the sign of $2x$ is right, you your mistaken has started in first line.

Comment: In the third step when u take u=x+1 , Why did u put u in place of (x-1)^2 as u^2?You have written (x-1)^2 instead of (x+1)^2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I changed the integral to $\int\frac{\sqrt{(x-1)^2-4}}{x+1}dx$ then $u=x+1$

It should be
$$\int\frac{\sqrt{(x\color{red}{+}1)^2-4}}{x+1}dx$$

> I simplified to $2\int tan^2\theta d\theta$ = $2\int\sec^2\theta-1d\theta$
> $=2[tan\theta-\theta]+C$
>
> back substitute $\theta=tan^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{u^2-4}}{2}$and $tan\theta=\frac{\sqrt{u^2-4}}{2}$ back substitute $u=x+1$

I think you did nothing wrong here.

> $\int\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x-3}}{x+1}dx={\sqrt{(x-1)^2-4}}-tan^{-1}{\sqrt{(x-1)^2-4}}+C$

This is not correct :
$$\int\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x-3}}{x+1}dx={\sqrt{(x\color{red}{+}1)^2-4}}-\color{red}{2}\tan^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{(x\color{red}{+}1)^2-4}}{\color{red}{2}}+C$$

Comment: than you @mathlove

Answer (score 2):

> You've made a mistake. I hope you can find it using my answer

$$\int\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x-3}}{x+1}\space\text{d}x=\int\frac{\sqrt{(x+1)^2-4}}{x+1}\space\text{d}x=$$

---

Substitute $u=x+1$ and $\text{d}u=\text{d}x$:

---

$$\int\frac{\sqrt{u^2-4}}{u}\space\text{d}u=$$

---

Substitute $u=2\sec(s)$ and $\text{d}u=2\tan(s)\sec(s)\space\text{d}s$.

We get that $\sqrt{u^2-4}=\sqrt{4\sec^2(s)-4}=2\tan(s)$ and $s=\text{arcsec}\left(\frac{u}{2}\right)$:

---

$$2\int\tan^2(s)\space\text{d}s=2\int\left[\sec^2(s)-1\right]\space\text{d}s=2\left[\int\sec^2(s)\space\text{d}s-\int1\space\text{d}s\right]$$

Notice now, the integral of $\sec^2(s)$ is equal to $\tan(s)$ and the integral of $1$ is just $s$.